# Galera cluster donor node changed

Tags: cluster, galera

I just started node1 as donor with ‘/etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster’.
Then started second node.
and check "show status like 'wsrep%'" in mysql.
but the second’s wsrep_local_index became 0 and first node became 1.

Also started third node
and now first node became 2 and third node became 0.

Why donor node changed?
I can’t understand.
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [official documentation](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/nodeprovisioning.html) you'll see this:

> When using automatic donor selection, starting in Galera Cluster
>   version 3.6, the cluster decides which state transfer method to use
>   based on availability.
>
> - If there are no nodes available that can safely perform an incremental state transfer, the cluster defaults to a state snapshot
>     transfer.
> - If there are nodes available that can safely perform an incremental state transfer, the cluster prefers a local node over remote nodes to
>     serve as the donor.
> - If there are no local nodes available that can safely perform an incremental state transfer, the cluster chooses a remote node to serve
>     as the donor.
> - Where there are several local or remote nodes available that can safely perform an incremental state transfer, the cluster chooses the
>     node with the highest seqno to serve as the donor.

Comment: As I know donor node is first started node but it can be changed? why and how???

Comment: @user448347 yes, it could be changed manually or automatically. Here [old post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/08/finding-good-ist-donor-percona-xtradb-cluster-5-6/) from Percona blog about it.